# index a large number of xml files to solr 5

Tags: solr, solr5

I am trying to index ~1 million of xml files to Solr 5. There are a few ways I can think of:

1. dump all the xml files into a directory and then use post.jar
2. It seems to me that data import handler can also be used to recursively import xml files

Are there any other ways?

Comment: You could make your own indexer in your favourite language which would parse the xml files, make any modifications you might want and send them to the solr server using a solr client library.

Comment: Check this blog post http://www.andornot.com/blog/post/Sample-Solr-DataImportHandler-for-XML-Files.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is how to index one million xml-files with solr.

You can use the [bin/post](https://lucidworks.com/blog/2015/08/04/solr-5-new-binpost-utility/)-tool even with recursiv folder structure.

If this has enough functionality: fine. If you need more special features build your own indexer, in particular with [solrj](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+SolrJ#UsingSolrJ-IndexingDocuments) this is quite easy.

If you have enough main memory you can use `DataImportHandler` with [FileListEntityProcessor](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler#UploadingStructuredDataStoreDatawiththeDataImportHandler-TheFileListEntityProcessor). ´FileListEntityProcessor´ first collects all files and than run through the real indexing. So in your case the first step will put one million instances of "File" in your main memory.